# Generate c# image object with canvas todataurl

Tags: c#, image, object, canvas

How can i make a Bitmap or Image object with the code generated by canvas.toimageurl() method?

The string looks like this: `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQA...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. A small amount of [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)
2. a bit of [Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx)
3. bake with the [MemoryStream .ctor taking a byte array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa328939.aspx)
4. add a [Bitmap .ctor taking a stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw.aspx)
5. Serve hot

Sample code just for fun :

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Program
{
    static string data = @"data:image/png;base64,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";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var base64Data = Regex.Match(data, @"data:image/(?<type>.+?),(?<data>.+)").Groups["data"].Value;
        var binData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(binData))
        {
            var pictureBox = new PictureBox {
                Image = new Bitmap(stream),
            };

            var form = new Form { AutoSize = true, AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink };
            form.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok this worked, but when i save the bmp, it saves just a black image!
what could be wrong?
or do i have to provide some options?

Comment: I don't know but i'm mostly using pngs maybe it have something to do with the original jpg format. Do you really need to convert to bitmap ? if not why not just seek to the begining of the stream and save it to a file ?

Comment: btw: do you know how i can check if the hole image is one color? like
if the hole image is red?

Comment: It's pretty simple with linq if you don't care about performance : return (from x in Enumerable.Range(0, bitmap.Width)
                    from y in Enumerable.Range(0, bitmap.Height)
                    select bitmap.GetPixel(x, y)).All(c => c == Color.Red);